Is Incremental Migration to Jetpack Compose Navigation Possible with Mixed Traditional Fragment Navigation?
I am currently working on migrating our application from using traditional fragment-based navigation to Jetpack Compose Navigation. All our screens are currently built with fragments that utilize ComposeView. Our goal is to transition to Jetpack Compose Navigation, but rather than doing this all at once, we'd like to manage it incrementally by integrating Compose Navigation alongside the existing fragment-based navigation.
From my initial research, including insights from the Android documentation and discussions on relevant issue, it seems that a mixed navigation system combining both traditional fragments and Compose might not be straightforward or supported.
Specifically, integrating traditional Fragment-based navigation with Compose Navigation within the same NavHost presents significant challenges.
However, I am concerned about the complexity and potential risks of migrating all components at once to Compose Navigation. I am looking for advice or examples from anyone who has successfully implemented a mixed navigation system or managed an incremental migration to Compose Navigation.
How can I integrate Compose Navigation incrementally with existing fragment-based screens? Are there any strategies, tools, or techniques that could facilitate this type of migration?

I can tell you from experience facing this same issue previously it was possible to do this migration migrating it by flow while keeping the flow itself in a fragment so it still in working with the old navigation by time you will have linked fragments each holding a navhost and Navigations from this point its easier to just neglect the fragments and start combining them in higher navhosts the main issue you will face is the placement of the navhost unless you are only navigating between screens
